# Can I restore a previous Chrome session from May 19?

Tags: google-chrome

Can I restore a previous Google Chrome session from May 19? I viewed someone's Linkedin profile that is now deleted and I need a record of it...

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot. The users URL for LinkedIn is now invalid. The only way you could see the persons profile again, is if you saved the web pages to your computer while you were on them.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately if their profile is deleted there is no way of accessing it again. When you access a web page you're making a request to the server for a specific file, if the file is not there then nothing can be done as very little information from websites is saved locally in your browser. Occasionally websites will cache information in your browser but it would not include an entire web page.